# how to operate on NSNumber in NSNArray created by NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray, nsnumber

i've got some method.

```
 ....{
 NSString *mean = @"1:1:1:1:1:1:1:1:1";
 tab = [self moveSourceArrayToDestinationArray:mean];
....}



-(NSArray*)moveSourceArrayToDestinationArray:(NSString*)sourceArray{
NSArray *destinationArray = [sourceArray componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

for (NSNumber *number in destinationArray) {
    sum += [number doubleValue];
}
NSLog(@"%d", [destinationArray objectAtIndex:1] * 5); // invalid operands to binary expression ('id' and 'int')
return destinationArray;
}
```

how can i do something mathematic operation on numbers in NSArray?

Comment: You still have NSNumbers in your NSArray. You need to convert those if you want to do some math with them.

Comment: There are no actual NSNumber objects anywhere in this code. They are NSStrings. He just got lucky with the selector names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to retrieve a numeric value from the NSNumber object, something you already did in your code snippet earlier.  For example, try:

```
NSLog(@"%d", [[destinationArray objectAtIndex:1] intValue] * 5);
```

See the full list of numeric access functions in the NSNumber documentation under the section titled "Accessing Numeric Values."

Comment: There are no actual NSNumber objects involved here.

Comment: Oh dear, you're right.  I just saw the for() loop and didn't look at how destinationArray was constructed.  Yes, this is a total mess... follow Adam's advice too.

Comment: Objective-C tries to be so nice but sometimes that just causes more harm than good :)

Answer (score 2):

Your reference to NSNumber in your code is a mistake, and you got lucky that your code didn't throw an unrecognized selector exception. Your `destinationArray` is an array of NSStrings, not NSNumbers. It just so happens that both `NSString` and `NSNumber` have `doubleValue` and `intValue` methods. So when you say `[number doubleValue]` in your loop, you actually end up calling `[NSString doubleValue]` which of course still returns the number you want. However, if you were to try to call `[number shortValue]`, where `shortValue` is a selector that only exists in `NSNumber` and not `NSString`, your code would throw an exception and not work.

The moral of this answer is that you should remove any reference to NSNumber in your code, or actually convert the objects in `destinationArray` to NSNumbers. Otherwise, you risk running into more trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Your object at `[destionationArray objectAtIndex:index]` is likely to be a NSNumber as well. Therefore, you have to to `[[destinationArray objectAtIndex:index] doubleValue]`at this point, too.